# targetting the next container child in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

i have created a couple of buttons at run time in flex. when i click on one button using `event.currentTarget` property i can change its properties like x,y,label etc , also i can get its index. Now i can found the next child index too but how can i change the properties of next child using its index.

Currently i am using  `getElementIndex(Button(event.currentTarget)).x` for changing its x coordinates. Need to change the coordinates of the button next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getChildAt(index + 1)` on the button's `parent`.